# Content in column not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following set up: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjPa/5/

Why does the text in the right column lower itself every time I add a new line in the left column? I need the line to start at the top of the column.

```
<div class="container">  
  <form class="form-large">
      <div class="left-col">line1<br />line2<br />line3</div>   
      <div class="right-col">this line should be at the top of this column</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
.form-large {
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 14px 14px 14px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.left-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 640px;
    padding-left: 11px;    
}
.right-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    /*border-left: 1px solid #d6d6d6;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to css of your right column.

OT: you have  width set 2 times.

Comment: That did the trick. One more thing, I added a vertical divider between both columns, but it only extends to the point where the content in the right column ends [http://i.imgur.com/z0PQd8t.png](http://i.imgur.com/z0PQd8t.png)

Here is the code: [http://jsfiddle.net/eGjPa/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/eGjPa/8/)

How do I make it extend to the bottom of the form?

Comment: Put a `border-right` on the left column, and a `border-left on the right column, then use a negative margin to put the two borders over top of each other (`.right-col { margin-left: -1px; }` will probably do the trick).

Comment: If you don't mind having right column as well till the bottom of the page, add width: 100%; to your right column.

Comment: Did you mean height: 100%? I tried that, but it didn't work: [http://i.imm.io/W1kX.png](http://i.imm.io/W1kX.png)

Comment: @ShadyPotato indeed, I meant height: 100%. But for percentage values to work, you need to have parent height to be defined. If you don't want to have fixed values, use thirdenders suggestion - it should draw the line till the bottom of bigger column.
Yu would need to add those lines for css of left-col: `border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    margin-right: -5px;`

Answer (score 0):

add `float: right` to your right column, and you may need to increase the width of the jsfiddle window.